# react-native-maps lags a lot after returning from screen which make API calls

Tags: react-native, maps, freeze, lag

I am using react-native-maps in my home screen and from there I navigate to different screens. Some screens make API calls. But after returning from those screens, maps lags a lot and its a very bad experience. I am using react-navigation. Has anyone faced this issue earlier.

Comment: What are those API calls you are making? Do they modify the map in any way, like adding markers? If that is the case, how much does it modify it? Can you share some code about the API calls? And finally, how to you handle state in your application?

Comment: Hello @gbrl thanks for the reply. There was a mistake in my analysis. Actual issue was related to bottom sheet being kept open when I try to navigate to another screen. When I close the sheet and navigate, no lag is experienced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a mistake in my analysis. Actual issue was related to bottom sheet being kept open when I try to navigate to another screen. When I close the sheet and navigate, no lag is experienced